# Why does the count variable have to be defined outside the curly brackets of the for loop?

Tags: java, loops

In the two methods below, I get different results when I use the count variable outside the for loop curly brackets. Can someone please tell me why?

The first loop only prints three `i` values.
So my question is why the count variable can not be defined in the curly brackets of the for loop as I have done in the second method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

        System.out.println(i);
        count++;
        if (count == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(i);
        count++;
        if (count == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you think you *wouldn't* get different results?

Comment: It can. But it will produce a different result since everything inside the curly brackets of a for loop is executed at every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: It can be defined inside, but this has a different meaning. It is reset to 0 at each loop iteration.

Comment: Actually, you **can**, it's just that the result will be different.

Comment: `int count = 0; count++;` is effectively just a verbose way to write `int count = 1;`. And then it's obviously never equal to 3.

Comment: Why people downvote the rookie question? IMHO the question (Heshan's problem) is clear to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `count` would reset to `0` on every iteration of the loop (also `count` would no longer be visible after the loop)! **But**, you don't need `count` in the first place (since you have `i` and `count` is effectively `i + 1` - and would be three after loop) -

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i + 1 == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @josejuan We don't `count` to know that the value was three (in this case). Obviously scope matters in real code, but my main point here is `count` is a simple surrogate for `i`.

Comment: Of course, I get your point but obviously he don't understand the variable scope. You solve the problem without explaining their real (in the question) problem. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the 2nd loop, it will set  `int count` equal to 0, and then `count++` will increment `count` by 1 so it will become equal to 1, and every time the loop increment `i` by 1 the same thing will happen again(which is set `int count` to 0,then increment it by 1 and then ...) so `i` will keep increment until it reaches the value 4 and exit out of the `for loop` , but in your first `for loop` since the `int count` is not declared inside it, `int count` will not be changed to 0 again and thus it will increment by 1 without being re-set to 0, so when `count` will be equal to 3, you'll exit the `for loop` since you "told" your `for loop` to break when `count==3`

Comment: @josejuan this does not directly answer his question

Comment: He change the count's scope, I think it is the central point.